# Where condition in Couchbase lite

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

I have some logic issue in Couchbase Lite. Here is my db data like below

```
"3 step", 50.00, 4, "step"
"3 step", 50.00, 3, "step"
"3 step", 50.00, 3, "step"
"3 step", 50.00, 4, "step"
"3 step", 50.00, 7, "step"
"3 step", 50.00, 2, "step"
"3 step", 50.00, 2, "step"
"3 step", 50.00, 1, "step"
"3 step", 50.00, 2, "step"
"3 step", 50.00, 3, "step"
```

4,3,3,4,7 this single step of the day
4 is a start step 7 is a end step.

which ever > than 5 is end step very next one is start step
how can i can get only start step and end step value?

i tried with like below

```
 while (rowEnum.hasNext()) {
     Document gpsData = rowEnum.next().getDocument();
     int stepDiff = (int) gpsData.getProperty("stepdiff");
     if (start){
         startStepArray.add((String) gData.getProperty("stepsDiff"));
         start = false;
     }
     if (diffTime > 5) {
         endStepArray.add((String) gData.getProperty("stepsDiff"));
         start = true;
     }
}
```

But this logic will not work if there is no >5

can some one guide me how can i achieve this?

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking `if (stepDiff > 5)`? Otherwise, what is `diffTime`?

Comment: Also, you have `gData` instead of `gpsData` and `getProperty("stepsDiff")` instead of `getProperty("stepdiff")`... Basically, it is hard to tell what you are trying to do without a little more information, such as the schema of your database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your problem is, but just throwing this simple example together seems to work fine.

#### Data wrapper object

```
class Document {
    private String s1, s4;
    private double d2;
    private int i3;

    public Document(String arg0, double arg1, int arg2, String arg3) {
        this.s1 = arg0;
        this.d2 = arg1;
        this.i3 = arg2;
        this.s4 = arg3;
    }

    public int getStepDiff() {
        return this.i3;
    }
}
```

#### Driver class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Document> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    lst.add(new Document("3 step", 50.00, 4, "step"));
    lst.add(new Document("3 step", 50.00, 3, "step"));
    lst.add(new Document("3 step", 50.00, 3, "step"));
    lst.add(new Document("3 step", 50.00, 4, "step"));
    lst.add(new Document("3 step", 50.00, 7, "step"));
    lst.add(new Document("3 step", 50.00, 2, "step"));
    lst.add(new Document("3 step", 50.00, 2, "step"));
    lst.add(new Document("3 step", 50.00, 1, "step"));
    lst.add(new Document("3 step", 50.00, 2, "step"));
    lst.add(new Document("3 step", 50.00, 3, "step"));
    Iterator<Document> rowEnum = lst.iterator();

    /** Your logic starts here **/
    boolean start = true;
    List<String> startStepArray = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> endStepArray = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rowEnum.hasNext()) {
        Document gpsData = rowEnum.next();
        int stepDiff = gpsData.getStepDiff();

        if (start) {
            startStepArray.add(String.valueOf(gpsData.getStepDiff()));
            start = false;
        }

        if (stepDiff > 5) {
            endStepArray.add(String.valueOf(gpsData.getStepDiff()));
            start = true;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(startStepArray); // [4, 2]
    System.out.println(endStepArray); // [7]
}
```

If all the data were less than or equal to 5 (say the 7 was a 3) and you wanted the very last document to be an end-step, you could change this one line to do that.

```
if (stepDiff > 5 || !rowEnum.hasNext()) {
```

Then you would have a start-step of `[4]`, and an end-step of `[3]`. Or, keep the 7, and the start-steps would be `[4, 2]` and end-steps would be `[7, 3]`.